# WebView exception and setOverScrollMode

Tags: android, exception, webview

My tablet runs android 4.2.2.

I use a simple webview for depicting a javascript plot in a RelativeLayout. This is my simple **fragment_plot.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rl_plot"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" > 

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/wv_plot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >
</WebView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Within my Fragment's OnCreateView I inflate the fragment_plot.xml:

```
@Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_plot, container, false);
     return v;
 ;
```

Even though the program seems to work ( I do see the plot from the webview), each time I load the view, I get the following exception in my logcat:

```
webview(5289): setOverScrollMode: 1
webview(5289): java.lang.Exception
webview(5289):  at android.webkit.WebViewClassic.setOverScrollMode(WebViewClassic.java:1808)
webview(5289):  at android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.java:1918)
webview(5289):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3240)
webview(5289):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3284)
webview(5289):  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:431)
webview(5289):  at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(AbsoluteLayout.java:52)
webview(5289):  at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:504)
webview(5289):  at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:481)
webview(5289):  at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:461)
webview(5289):  at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:450)
webview(5289):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
webview(5289):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
webview(5289):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
webview(5289):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
webview(5289):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
webview(5289):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
webview(5289):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
webview(5289):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
webview(5289):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
webview(5289):  at com.fragments.PlotFragment.onCreateView(MenuPlotFragment.java:104)
webview(5289):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
```

I have tried to change the overscrollmode in the webview to *"always"* ( = 0), *"ifContentScrolls"* ( = 1) and *"never"* ( = 2) but each time I get the same exception.

Does anyone have any suggestion how I can deal with this exception?

Thanx!

Comment: The `WebViewClassic` class doesn't explicitly throw an exception, it's actually quite simple (taken from the 4.2.2_r1 sources):

    @Override
    public void setOverScrollMode(int mode) {
        if (mode != View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER) {
            if (mOverScrollGlow == null) {
                mOverScrollGlow = new OverScrollGlow(this);
            }
        } else {
            mOverScrollGlow = null;
        }
    }

It really doesn't do much at all and that exception isn't very specific.  There's bound to be something else going on in your setup.

Comment: This exception appears only on one tablet (MLS tablet 7-inch with android 4.2.2). There is not even a "Caused by:" clause in the logcat so that I can understand where might be the problem. I don't see the exception on other 7, 8 inch tablets or the emulator.

Comment: It may be something in that particular build of Android for that specific device then.  It's certainly not something obvious in the AOSP sources.